# fill 5*5 matrix in R using for loop with -1, 0 and 1 in equal proportion

Tags: r

I have to fill matrix with `-1`, `0` and `1` . I know how it can be done with single line command i.e `matrix(-1:1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)` and it give result like this:

```
-1  1  0 -1  1
 0 -1  1  0 -1
 1  0 -1  1  0
-1  1  0 -1  1
 0 -1  1  0 -1
```

I want same output via for loop. Can someone help me?

Comment: Your `matrix` command will result in `warning`

Comment: Am I allowed to ask why in a foor loop? And just the output or also the creation?

Comment: How would you fill a matrix with 25 cells with three different values (-1, 0, 1) in equal proportion? That is mathematically impossible, as 25/3 is not an integer.

Comment: i also need the creation as well plus according to query matrix should be of 50*50 and elements ratio should be more or less same and further have to create 100 non-identical matrices like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
m <- matrix(rep(NA, 25), 5, 5)
m
for(i in seq_along(m)) m[i] <- (-1:1)[i%%3+1]
m
```

Comment: But can't it be done by for loop only without using any R function. since I am new in programming.

Comment: @KritikaRajain If you don't want to use any R functions, why do you use R?

Comment: @www This is my task, don't have an option.

Comment: @KritikaRajain It is hard for me to believe that your task is "Use R, but do not use any R functions" as everything in R other than variable is function. Good luck on your task.

Comment: @KritikaRajain It is like "Give me a cup of ice tea but with no tea in it".

Comment: To create a matrix you will at least need the `matrix` function I guess. For a for loop you need at least the `for` function. `seq_along` is needed to check the length of your matrix, so it is universal, even if you use a 6x6 or so. 
But in general @www is correct, everything is a function in `R`. Even the `[` is a function...